# Google Scripts - delay loop for SMS texting script

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am hitting a Carrier limit when sending out requests to buy item's from sellers.

> 15-60 messages per minute and under 200 unique recipients a day

How can I stay within the following guidelines if I have 200-500 contacts in my spreadsheet for the script

```
function sendSms(to, body) {
  var messages_url = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/MYAPIKEY/Messages.json";

  var payload = {
    "To": to,
    "Body" : body,
    "From" : "+1PHONENUMBER"
  };

  var options = {
    "method" : "post",
    "payload" : payload
  };

  options.headers = { 
    "Authorization" : "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode("MYAPIKEY:MYAUTHTOKEN")
  };

  UrlFetchApp.fetch(messages_url, options);
}

function sendAll() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2; 
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow() - 1; 
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 3); // Modified
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    if (row[2].toLowerCase() != "sent") { // Added
      try {
        response_data = sendSms(row[0], row[1]);
        status = "sent";
      } catch(err) {
        Logger.log(err);
        status = "error";
      }
      sheet.getRange(startRow + Number(i), 3).setValue(status);
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you any help!

Answer (score 1):

This guarantees less than 15 per minute and if you put 200 recipients or less on sheets named for the days of the week (i.e. Sunday,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday).  Actually you can name them anything you want and use the names over again within the same week as long as you have less that 200 recipients on any one sheet then you be limiting yourself to the maximum number per day.

```
function sendAll() {
  var shA=['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];//sheet names
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(shA[new Date().getDay()])
  var startRow = 2; 
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow() - 1; 
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 3); // Modified
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    if (row[2].toLowerCase() != "sent") { // Added
      try {
        response_data = sendSms(row[0], row[1]);
        status = "sent";
      } catch(err) {
        Logger.log(err);
        status = "error";
      }
      sheet.getRange(startRow + Number(i), 3).setValue(status);
      Utilities.sleep(4000);//4 seconds
    }
  }
}
```

- [Utilities.sleep()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleep(Integer))
- [Date().getDay()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay)